# In an onclick handler, how can I detect whether shift was pressed?

Tags: javascript

How can I write an onclick handler that does one thing for regular clicks and a different thing for shift-clicks?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can look at the click event's shiftKey property.

```js
window.addEventListener("click",
  function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) console.log("Shift, yay!");
  },
  false);
```

```html
<p>Click in here somewhere, then shift-click.</p>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure you pass `event` as a parameter to your `onclick` function.  You can pass other parameters as well.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSomething(event, chkbox)
        {
            if (event.shiftKey)
                alert('Shift key was pressed while picking ' + chkbox.value);
            else
                alert('You picked ' + chkbox.value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Pick a Color</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="myColors" onclick="doSomething(event, this)" value="Red" /> Red<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="myColors" onclick="doSomething(event, this)" value="Green" /> Green<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="myColors" onclick="doSomething(event, this)" value="Blue" /> Blue<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The event fired from the DOM ought to contain a `shiftKey` (or equivalent) property indicating the state of the shift key when the event was fired; see, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey for an example.

If you're using a JavaScript/DOM wrapping library such as YUI, Prototype or jQuery, any differences in implementation ought not to be an issue.