# Problems with adding keyboard support to JS calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

I want to add keyboard support to my calculator. When i press operations with keyboard (i.e. +,-,* or /) js sees it as number, not as operation.

For example, when I compute "10+11" by clicking, I will get "21" as a result. When I do the same with inputing through keyboard, I will get "10".

Why does it happen? And is it possible to change it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div id="output">
                <input id="display" value="0">
            </div>
            <button class="clear" id="ce">CE</button>
            <button class="clear" id="c">C</button>
            <button class="operation" id="slash">/</button>
            <button class="number" id="seven">7</button>
            <button class="number" id="eight">8</button>
            <button class="number" id="nine">9</button>
            <button class="operation" id="star">*</button>
            <button class="number" id="four">4</button>
            <button class="number" id="five">5</button>
            <button class="number" id="six">6</button>
            <button class="operation" id="minus">-</button>
            <button class="number" id="one">1</button>
            <button class="number" id="two">2</button>
            <button class="number" id="three">3</button>
            <button class="operation" id="plus">+</button>
            <button class="number" id="zero">0</button>
            <button class="decimal" id="dot">.</button>
            <button class="operation" id="equal">=</button>
                </div>
        
        <script>
let numberBtn=document.querySelectorAll(".number"),
    operationBtn=document.querySelectorAll(".operation"),
    clearBtn=document.querySelectorAll(".clear"),
    decimalBtn=document.querySelector(".decimal"),
    currentValue=0,
    isNewValue= false,
    currentOperation=null,
    phrase="ошибка";
    display=document.getElementById('display');

    for (let i=0; i<operationBtn.length; i++) {
        operations=operationBtn[i];
        operations.addEventListener ('click', function (e) {
            operate (e.target.textContent);
        });
    }

    for (let i=0; i<operationBtn.length; i++) {
        op=operationBtn[i];
        op.addEventListener ('keypress', function (e) {
            operate (e.key);
        });
    }
    for (let i=0; i<numberBtn.length; i++) {
    numbers=numberBtn[i];
    
    numbers.addEventListener ('click', function (e) {
        numberPress (e.target.textContent);
        
    });
}

for (let i=0; i<numberBtn.length; i++) {
    numbers=numberBtn[i];
    numbers.addEventListener ('keypress', function (e) {
        numberPress (e.key)
    });
}



for (let i=0; i<clearBtn.length; i++) {
    clears=clearBtn[i];
    clears.addEventListener ('click', function (e) {
        console.log (e.srcElement.id);
        clear(e.srcElement.id);
    });
}

function numberPress(numbers) {
    if (isNewValue) {
        display.value=numbers;
        isNewValue=false;
        console.log ('1');
    } else {
        if (display.value==0 && display.value!=='0.') {
        display.value=numbers;
        console.log ('2');
        } else {
            display.value+=numbers;
            console.log ('3');
        }
    }
    }


function operate(op) {
    localOperationMemory=display.value;
    if (isNewValue && currentOperation!=="=") {
        currentValue=display.value;
        console.log ('4');
    } else {
        isNewValue=true;
        if (currentOperation=="+") {
            currentValue+=parseFloat (localOperationMemory);
            console.log ('5');
        } else if (currentOperation=="-") {
            currentValue-=parseFloat(localOperationMemory);
            console.log ('6');
        } else if (currentOperation=="*") {
            currentValue*=parseFloat (localOperationMemory);
            console.log ('7');
        } else if (currentOperation=="/") {
            currentValue/=parseFloat (localOperationMemory);
            console.log ('8');
        } else {
            currentValue=parseFloat (localOperationMemory);
            console.log ('9');
        }
        display.value=(Math.round(currentValue*100)/100);
        currentOperation=op;
        divideZero ()
    }
}

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In an onclick handler, how can I detect whether shift was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723290/in-an-onclick-handler-how-can-i-detect-whether-shift-was-pressed)

Comment: you call method divideZero in you solution and it's not there.

Comment: @Лиза Карпович Does my answer help you? If so, would you like to accept it?

Comment: `currentOperation` is null when you check what operation will execute and you assign it `currentOperation = op` when the `if` statements finish

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. It's not got any functionality for delete key or arrow keys, but it will perhaps help move you forward more. (nor negative numbers... where you start with a minus sign. You'd have to do something like 1-2= then multiply that to get the desired result).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script>
      var values
      var dp
      function checkCalcKey(key) {
        switch (key) {
          case '.':
            document.getElementById('dot').click();
            break;
          case '0':
          case '1':
          case '2':
          case '3':
          case '4':
          case '5':
          case '6':
          case '7':
          case '8':
          case '9':
          case '+':
          case '-':
          case '/':
          case '*':
          case '=':
            document.getElementById(key).click();
            break;
        }
        return false;
      // TODO handle any of 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Delete','Backspace'. I'll leave this as an exercise for you to complete!
      }
      function hardReset() {
          values = [];
          opcode = null;
          clear = true;
          reset();
      }
        
      function reset() {
        newNumber = false;
        if (opcode === null) {
           clearDisplay()
        }    
      }
        
      function clearDisplay() {
          dp = 0;
          nc = 0;
          document.getElementById('display').value = '';
      }
        
      function getValue() {
          var value;
          var s = '' + document.getElementById('display').value;
          if (s === '') {
              value = 0;
          } else if (s.indexOf('.') === -1) {
            value = Number(s);
          } else {
            value = parseFloat(s);
          }
          return value;
      }
        
      function performMaths() {
            m = values.pop();
            v = values.pop();
            switch (opcode) {
              case '+':
                v += m;
                break;
              case '-':
                v -= m;
                break;
              case '*':
                v *= m;
                break;
              case '/':
                if ( m=== 0) {
                   v = NaN;
                } else {
                   v /= m;
                }
                break;
            }
            values = [v,m];
            document.getElementById('display').value = v;
      }
        
      function init() {
        clear = true;
        hardReset();
        document.querySelectorAll(".number").forEach((b) => {
           b.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
              {
                newNumber = true;
                if (clear) {
                    clearDisplay();
                    clear = false;
                }
                nc++;
                display=document.getElementById('display');
                if (dp === 0) {
                   var value = (10 * Number(display.value)) + Number(e.target.textContent);
                   display.value = value;
                } else {
                   var f = Number(e.target.textContent) / Math.pow(10,dp);
                   var value = parseFloat(display.value);
                   var value = f + value;
                   var sv = '' + value
                   sv = sv.substring(0,nc);
                   display.value = sv;
                   dp++;
                }
              });
         });
          
         document.getElementById('dot').addEventListener('click', () => {
            newNumber = true;
            if (dp === 0) {
                dp++;
                nc++;
            }
         });
          
         document.getElementById('c').addEventListener('click', () => {
            hardReset();
         });
          
         document.getElementById('ce').addEventListener('click', () => {
            reset();
         });
          
         document.querySelectorAll(".operator").forEach((b) => {
           b.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
              {
                clear = true;
                if (e.target.textContent != opcode) {
                  opcode = e.target.textContent;
                }
                if (document.getElementById('display').value != '') {
                  if (values.length === 2) {
                      values.shift();
                  }
                 values.unshift(getValue());
                }
               newNumber = false;
              });
         });
          
         document.getElementById('=').addEventListener('click', () => {
           if (values.length === 2) {
              if (newNumber) {
                values.pop();
                values.push(getValue());
              }
           } else {
             values.push(getValue());
           }
           performMaths();
           newNumber = false;
         });
      }
        
    </script>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div class="main">
            <div id="output">
                <input id="display" value="" onkeydown="return checkCalcKey(event.key)">
            </div>
            <button id="ce">CE</button>
            <button id="c">C</button>
            <button id="0" class="number">0</button>
            <button id="1" class="number">1</button>
            <button id="2" class="number">2</button>
            <button id="3" class="number">3</button>
            <button id="4" class="number">4</button>
            <button id="5" class="number">5</button>
            <button id="6" class="number">6</button>
            <button id="7" class="number">7</button>
            <button id="8" class="number">8</button>
            <button id="9" class="number">9</button>
            <button id="/" class="operator">/</button>
            <button id="*" class="operator">*</button>
            <button id="-" class="operator">-</button>
            <button id="+" class="operator">+</button>
            <button id="=">=</button>
            <button id="dot">.</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*An explanation of the code:*

The **getValue** routine does the bulk of fixing things up, and answers the key points in your original question:

- If a variable is being interpreted as of type string it can mess up the computation.
  So you can convert a variable you don't know the type of to string by
  combining an empty string with the variable itself.
- There is code to check for the existence of a decimal point, then use either **parseFloat** or **Number** to *cast* the type of the variable (*[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)* is a more verbose alternative, needing radix of 10 - for a base 10 number).
- A couple of other key variables are:

  - **dp** (decimal point). It stands for the number of digits past the decimal point, so any numbers you add after are divided by 10^dp (so 1 digit after dp is *n* * 1/10th, 2 digits is *n* * 1/100th etc).
  - **nc** (number of characters). Sometimes you can get odd rounding errors, so things like 1.111 suddenly become 1.111000000001 or something like that, so **nc** is used to count digits and decimal places entered and take the left number of characters based on **nc**.

There is also some funky stuff going on, mimicking a normal calculator.
So that when computation goes on, you can do something like enter:

- 5 * = to give 25..
- Press = again and it will give you 125.

So the *last* number you enter becomes like a 'sticky' constant in memory. Whenever a new value gets entered, that becomes the new 'sticky' value. So:

- 3 * 4 = (yields 12),
- = then yields 48 etc.

So:

- the **values** array is used to store both the sticky value and the total:
- It gets re-evaluated in **performMaths()**
- adjusted in **operator** and **=** event handlers.
- the boolean **newValue** is set to *true* whenever a number is pressed, and *false* whenever an operation, such as `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` or `=` is pressed.

**checkCalcKey()** is an event handler for *onkeydown* upon the *input* HTML control's. By returning `false`, it prevents the character you type from build input. Instead it defers to the click handler of the corresponding button and any character entry into the input control *value* property gets performed via that handler instead. (More info [here](https://javascript.info/keyboard-events)).